# Use include_vars in sub playbook from parent playbook

Tags: import, ansible, include, var, ansible-facts

I have a playbook `playbook.yml`, which import sub playbooks, and I want to include `play2.yml` conditionally based on `my_app_vars[key1]`

```yaml
- import_playbook: play1.yml
- import_playbook: play2.yml
  when: {{ my_app_vars[key1] }}
  vars:
    key1: "{{mock_key}}"
```

in `play1.yml`, I have

```yaml
- name: "Get Some Info"
  hosts: mock_servers
  pre_tasks:
    - name:
      include_vars:
        file: mock-vars.yml
        name: my_app_vars
      register: "{{my_app_vars}}"  #adding register did not help
```

After execution, I get the error `my_app_vars is undefined`, after adding `register`, still get the same error.

I could use `my_app_vars`, `mock_key` and `key1` under a `role` correctly in `play2.yml`.

But now I want to use `my_app_vars`, `mock_key` and `key1` in `playbook.yml`, is there any way to achieve it?
I use ansible-playbook-2.8.1, thanks in advance

---

**Update:**

follow answer from @β.εηοιτ.βε, I tried below [no `register` in  `play1.yml`]

```
when: not ( {{ hostvars[groups[mock_servers][0]].my_app_vars[key1] }} )
''mock_servers'' is undefined'

when: not ( {{ hostvars[groups['mock_servers'][0]].my_app_vars[key1] }} )
''ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object'' has no attribute ''my_app_vars'''

when: not ( {{ hostvars[groups.mock_servers.0].my_app_vars[key1] }} )
''ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object'' has no attribute ''my_app_vars'''

when: not ( {{ hostvars[groups.mock_servers.0] }}.my_app_vars[key1] )
''dict object'' has no attribute ''my_app_vars'
```

---

**After add `gather_facts: false`, work as expected, fantastic**

Comment: Where is `mock_key` coming from?

Answer (score 2):

This is implicitly stated in the last bullet point of the module synopsis:

> - To assign included variables to a different host than `inventory_hostname`, use `delegate_to` and set `delegate_facts=yes`.

*<sup>Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#synopsis</sup>*

Which means the variables included by `include_vars` are actual stored as **hosts** variables.

This means, that, in order to access them in your main playbook, that includes the two other playbooks and which is not selecting any hosts or groups, you will have to access those via the [`hotsvars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-hostvars) special variable.

In your case it could be something like:

```yaml
when: hostvars[groups.mock_servers.0].my_app_vars[key1]
```

---

An example of that behaviour would be as follow.

*play.yml*:

```yaml
- import_playbook: play1.yml
  
- import_playbook: play2.yml
  when: hostvars[groups.group1.0].vars_of_play1.foo == 'bar'
```

*play1.yml*:

```yaml
- hosts: group1
  gather_facts: false

  pre_tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: vars.yml
        name: vars_of_play1
```

*vars.yml*:

```yaml
foo: bar
```

*play2.yml*:

```yaml
- hosts: group2
  gather_facts: false

  pre_tasks:
    - debug:
```

Which would, as expected, run the second playbook:

```bash
$ ansible-playbook play.yml 

PLAY [group1] ************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] ******************************************************
ok: [ansible-node-1]

PLAY [group2] ************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [ansible-node-2] => 
  msg: Hello world!
```